# Google App Engine - set index/home page

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

from what I understand, the app.yaml file in a Google App Engine project, can serve a file as a 'home' page. When I navigate to my domain, however, it always gives me a 404. My app.yaml is in the war directory. This is what my app.yaml looks like:

```
application: therealtest
version: 10
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: site/index-static.html
  upload: site/index-static\.html
```

What I am expecting it to do is to display the page index-static.html when I go to the domain of the site, but it does not. Is this not the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the site directory inside your war directory?  It should be, given that is where you said your app.yaml file is.

FWIW, putting your web app in a war directory implies to me that you're thinking in Java terms, but your app.yaml snippet tells us you're using Python.  In Java, WAR stands for Web Archive, which is a zip file with a certain required directories and files.

Comment: Everything is in the war directory. I did not know about the whole java/python thing though. Is there a way to configure a landing page using java that I'm not aware of? thanks!

Comment: Denim, it sounds like you're not very clear on how App Engine works, so to help you I think you'll need to be more explicit about what exactly is in your war directory, and what you did to upload it to Google App Engine.  -- James

Comment: I used eclipse to create the directory, uploaded html files into the war directory, and simply deployed to appengine. You can call me alex by the way, that is just my username.